# Node.js and PostgreSQL Join Process

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

There is a table in the database as follows. The thing I want to ask is there is another table corresponding to the "Example 2" text in the title section. Likewise, there is another table corresponding to the "Example 3" text. What I want to do is to bring the data in the example 2 table instead of the example 2 text. Thank you for your help.[image]

here is the Example 2 table and example table
[image]

When I try to get the table example it gives this output as json

[image]

But what I want is not a text in the example 2 section, but an object containing the information in the example 2 table

Comment: Show all three table structures. Show what you have in tables `Example 2` and `Example 3` and what you wish to get from them and with what conditions

Comment: No one on this end of the internet know if there is another table in your database.  That is information you should have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've elaborated my question a little bit more.